# WHEN condition based on the current row value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, case

In my `SELECT` query, I would like to put a condition in my `CASE` for a value called *IsActive* so that if the current row's column Type is *"adhoc"* then set the value of IsActive to "n/a".

```
SELECT CASE Type
            WHEN 'scheduled' THEN 'Scheduled'
            WHEN 'adhoc' THEN 'AdHoc'
            ELSE 'Unknown'
       END AS 'Type',
       CASE IsActive 
            WHEN (Type) = 'adhoc' THEN 'n/a'
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Stopped'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Active'
       END AS 'Status'
FROM MyTable
```

But I am getting this error on the line `WHEN (Type) = 'adhoc' THEN 'n/a'`:

> Incorrect syntax near '='.

How can I make a decision based on a condition on the current row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second `case` is based on a single column, then you are trying to put a condition in the `when`, which is not allowed:

```
CASE IsActive 
            WHEN (Type) = 'adhoc' THEN 'n/a'
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Stopped'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Active'
       END AS 'Status'
```

I think you meant to do this (use a `case` without a column and put the conditions in the `when`):

```
CASE 
WHEN [Type] = 'adhoc' THEN 'n/a'
WHEN IsActive = 0 THEN 'Stopped'
WHEN IsActive = 1 THEN 'Active'
END AS 'Status'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT (CASE Type
            WHEN 'scheduled' THEN 'Scheduled'
            WHEN 'adhoc' THEN 'AdHoc'
            ELSE 'Unknown'
        END) AS 'Type',
       (CASE 
            WHEN Type = 'adhoc' THEN 'n/a'
            WHEN IsActive = 0 THEN 'Stopped'
            WHEN IsActive = 1 THEN 'Active'
        END) AS 'Status'
FROM MyTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Pedram jaan your query will be like this:

```
SELECT CASE [Type]
            WHEN 'scheduled' THEN 'Scheduled'
            WHEN 'adhoc' THEN 'AdHoc'
            ELSE 'Unknown'
       END AS 'Type',
       CASE  
            WHEN [Type] = 'adhoc' THEN 'n/a'
            WHEN IsActive = 0 THEN 'Stopped'
            WHEN IsActive = 1 THEN 'Active'
       END AS 'Status'
FROM dbo.MyTable
```

Use Type in brackets like this [Type]. It's a keyword.

Comment: Pedram jaan? Lol. Mamnoon! Your answer is correct. But I'm afraid I'd have to choose the one that was posted earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE Type
        WHEN 'scheduled' THEN 'Scheduled'
        WHEN 'adhoc' THEN 'AdHoc'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
   END AS 'Type',
   CASE WHEN [Type] = 'adhoc' THEN 'n/a'                        
        WHEN IsActive = 0 THEN 'Stopped'
        WHEN IsActive = 1 THEN 'Active'
   END AS 'Status'
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

current computed row operations are not supported by MS Sql Server.
to achieve this goal you have to mention a Cte

```
with cteType as (
SELECT CASE Type
            WHEN 'scheduled' THEN 'Scheduled'
            WHEN 'adhoc' THEN 'AdHoc'
            ELSE 'Unknown'
       END AS 'Type'
FROM MyTable)

select Type
,
       CASE IsActive 
            WHEN (Type) = 'adhoc' THEN 'n/a'
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Stopped'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Active'
       END AS 'Status'
FROM cteType
```

This will work